# How to split a binary number represented as a string to sub strings

Tags: python, sorting, tkinter, replace

I am working with a binary file. and want to split a binary number to smaller parts.

For example an input number `01001100001011000100110000101100010011000` should be parsed to `0 1 00 11 0000 1 0 11 000 1 00 11 0000 1 0 11 000 1 00 11 000`.

This is what I have tried so far?

```
    from tkinter import filedialog
    
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        a = f.read
    
    print(a.replaceint("01", "0 1"))
    print(a.replaceint("10", "1 0"))
       
    print(f, file=open("space.txt", "a"))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider elaborating what you mean by grouping it in that particular way. Are you trying to implement a specific algorithm? It may also help you to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thank you!

Comment: Try `a = a.replace('01', '0 1').replace('10', '1 0')`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, let me know if you have any questions.

```py
import itertools

s = "01001100001011000100110000101100010011000"

for k,v in itertools.groupby(s):
    print(k*len(list(v)))
```