# Split a binary string into a list of same digits without a separator in Python?

Tags: python

I have a string in Python that I want to separate into a list without any separators.
The string is similar to a byte array: `'0100100010011'`

I want to separate the 1's and 0's from each other without using `string.split()` because that function requires a separator.

This should be my expected output: `['0', '1', '00', '1', '000', '1', '00', '11']`

Comment: Same thing previously asked [How to split a binary number represented as a string to sub strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63143766/how-to-split-a-binary-number-represented-as-a-string-to-sub-strings), but these answers are better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is a quick way to do this. Without a `key` argument it will group by the value of the items in an iterable (like a string). Then you can just join the groups:

```
from itertools import groupby

s = '0100100010011'
[''.join(g) for k, g in groupby(s)]
# ['0', '1', '00', '1', '000', '1', '00', '11']
```

One small advantage of itertools when dealing with a lot of data is that it allows you to iterate over a large set of things with needing to save the entire set to memory. So for example, you could process these one at a time without allocating the entire list:

```
for k, g in groupby(s):
    group = ''.join(g) 
    # deal with a single group and forget it
```

Comment: Short and sweet!

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions are an even easier way to do this.

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, May 27 2021, 13:30:53) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = '0010110111000111'
>>> import re
>>> ex = r"(0+|1+)"
>>> z = re.findall(ex,x)
>>> z
['00', '1', '0', '11', '0', '111', '000', '111']
>>>
```